# How to bind/referece grand parent property to/inside child knockout

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Hi guys looking for some basic advice.

I have four models: `BoardViewModel`, `List`, `Card`, `Member`

```
var Member = function (id, name, avatar) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.avatar = avatar;
    self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
};
```

I am instantiating members property inside `BoardViewModel`. But I want to use a copy of this model inside each `Card` model to instantiate a list of assigned members.

Each card stores comma separated list of member references like

```
",1,2,4,5"
```

I am writing a loop to `BoardViewModel.members` and mark members as checked if id references match bore I assign it as `Card.members`.

The last piece of the puzzle I am missing is reference to the `BoardViwModel.members`.

I have a lovely example [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/iiminov/88rafcfk/14/) that would somewhat help to build a picture of what I am talking about.

Just bear in mind that once I have this working properly I want to replace view() binding

```
foreach: $root.members
```

with

```
foreach: members
```

If at all possible I would like to avoid passing `BoardViewModel.members` as parameter into `List` and then into `Card`.

#### Update 1

As suggested by @Jeroen here's a simplified version of my [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/iiminov/88rafcfk/14/).

The top view() model which encompases a concept of lists:

```
var BoardViewModel = function (lists, members) {
    var self = this;

    // in reality members are fetched via ajax call to the server
    // and instantiate as a ko.observableArray()
    self.groupMembers = ko.observableArray(members);
    self.lists = ko.observableArray(lists);
    ...
}
```

In reality this has a signature like this:

```
var boardViewModel = function (initialData)
```

moving on.

The child `List` model which encompases a concept of cards:

```
var List = function (id, name, cards, sortOrder, groupMembers) {
    var self = this;

    self.cards = ko.observableArray(cards);
    ...
}
```

in reality:

```
var list = function (item, groupMembers)
```

nothing special there really.

The child `Card` model which encompases the concept of card items (but lets not go there yet):

```
var Card = function (id, title, description, contentItemId, members, groupMembers) {
    var self = this;

    self.members = ko.observableArray(parseMembers(members));

    // now remember each card has a members property
    // which stores comma separated list ",1,4"
    function (members) {
        var memberList = groupMembers;
        var memberRefList = members.split(',');
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(memberList, function(member){
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(memberRefList, function(memberId){
                if(member.id === meberId) {
                    member.isChecked(true);
                }
            });
        });
        return memberList;
    }
    ...
}
```

in reality:

```
var card = function (item, groupMembers)
```

nothing too fancy there either.

I currently have something like this working on my dev environment.

**Problem:**
Those with keen eyes probably noticed the way I was passing `groupMembers` all the way up. I am not particularly hyped about the idea.

Anyone know a better way of implementing this? i.e. why can't I just do something like

```
var memberList = self.parent.parent.groupMembers;
```

for instance.

Comment: Your question is well written but dependent on the (rather large) jsfiddle. Please reduce your fiddle to a [minimal repro](http://sscce.org), and include the repro *in the question itself*. In addition, it would help if you conclude with what the actual problem is (I understand the *situation* and kinda see the *requirement*, but not the question or problem). Perhaps telling us what you've tried and where/why you got stuck would help.

Comment: Hrm, my bad @Jeroen, I will update this soon with what I actually have working for me at the minute. So maybe someone here can share with me how to do the same think but better.

Comment: There we go. Nice, long and simple. Halp please :)

Answer (score 0):

As per me, the better way to do is to have the child viewmodels inside the parent view-model. like this where you can access the parent data members as well as methods directly.

**ViewModel**

```
var BoardViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.members = ko.observableArray();
    this.lists = ko.observableArray();

    // Child View Models
    this.Member = function(member){
        this.id = member.id;
        this.name = member.name;
        this.avatar = member.avatar;
        this.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
    }

    this.List = function(list){
        // same for this
    };

    this.Card = function(card){
        // same for this
    };

    // a Method to bind the data with the observables and arrays
    // Assuming data is a json object having Members, List objects
    this.applyData = function(data){
        self.members(jQuery.map(data.Members, function(item){
            return new self.Member(item);
        }));

        self.lists(jQuery.map(data.Lists, function(item){
            return new self.List(item);
        }));
    }
}
```

**onDom ready**

```
// json object holding your data
var data = {
    "Members" : [
    ],
    "Lists" : [
    ],
    "Cards" : [
    ]
};

var vm = new BoardViewModel();

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('myModule'));
    vm.applyData(data);
});
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll give it a shot. But is it just me or the way you defined ``var data`` indicated to me that Cards are not part of individual Lists. This parent-child relationship is kind of important. And when I get too defining children of Card class its going to be the same story.

Comment: @iiminov I simply defined `var data` as a json object as per the fiddle you provided. In the fiddle, you defined three objects with data and those data you passed to the view models separately. Here i merged those data into one json object and passing to the view-model where am assigning the values to there respective child view-models. In parent view-model, you can access or refer any child view-model or its property easily